# return each new array item in new line

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
let boss = [['Mark', 'Tom', 'Dave']]
    let newBoss = boss.map(function(r) {
        return r;
    })
```

returns `[ [ 'Mark', 'Tom', 'Dave' ] ]`

How can I make it to return the same values each on a new row for example:

```js
[
['Mark'],
['Tom'],
['Dave'],
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Map over `boss[0]`, not `boss`, and wrap each returned value in an array:

```js
const boss = [['Mark', 'Tom', 'Dave']]
const newBoss = boss[0].map(str => [str]);
console.log(newBoss);
```